# PyCharm: IDE does not seem to recognise Python 3 even with 3.x interpreter set

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, pycharm

I am using the latest version of Pycharm(pycharm-2017.1) and have used Pycharm for a couple of years without issue. However, I have never written Python 3 scripts with it before, and have issues now. I am getting red underlined syntax errors which appear to clearly indicate that Pycharm doesn't understand that I'm using Python 3.

[image: syntax error1]
[image: syntax error2]

In 'Edit configurations', I have set Python 3.x to be the default interpreter... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Edit configurations window]

Note: I have the correct python3 shebang lines in my scripts, and running them both straight from a terminal, or even by pressing 'run' in Pycharm works no problem.. this latter fact just adds to the mystery.

I also tried adding (with the '+' in 'Edit configurations', specific profiles for each of the scripts concerned, with Python3.x as the interpreters, to no avail)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Edit configurations` settings refers to the running options only.

To use python3 at project level you need to change the interpreter in `File > Settings > Project: project-name > Project Interpreter`

[image]

This allow to have correct syntax-checking, import-checking and others